# mysql_fetch_array returns 0 from a simple table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, mysqli

I have a table that it named `setting`.

I would like to get value where `key` equal `regCharg` :

[image]

```
    $result_gift = mysql_query("select value,key from setting WHERE key='regCharg'");
    $result_gift_row = mysql_fetch_array($result_gift);
    $finance = (float)$result_gift_row[2] ;
```

but it returns 0 value instead of 1000 .

[image]

(I know that I must use mysqli or PDO instead of mysql).

Comment: First: notice the dashed underline on array, that's probably a sql  reserved word. Second: mysql_query expects a second parameter (connection parameter).

Comment: @ADASein the connection parameter is optional!

Comment: @ADASein: `array` isn't reserved, but 'key' is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`key` is a reserved word. you can't use it "naked" in the query:

```
$result_gift = mysql_query("select value,`key` from setting WHERE `key`='regCharg'");
                                         ^---^---
```

If you had even barebones basic error handling in your script, you'd have been ifnormed about the syntax error:

```
   $result = mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You're getting `zero` because the query failed, returned boolean FALSE, and then you used that boolean false in your fetch operation, leading to further failures.

**NEVER** assume success when doing a database query. Always assume failure, check for that failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Answer (score 2):

You are only returning two fields from the database. When working with arrays the index starts at 0.

The array will be sorted in the order you have used in your SQL query.

Therefore you need to use `$result_gift_row[0]` to return the field value.
`result_gift_row[1]` would return the key field.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$finance = (float)$result_gift_row[1] ;
```

The arrays are indexed from 0 that's why you should find the second column at index 1